# How to generate and copy a list of all the symbols (variables and functions) defined in C?

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I have a file named common.h where all the variables and functions have been defined. Is there an easy way by which I could generate and copy the names of all the variables and functions defined ? I have more than 2,000 functions and variables defined all together and its futile to copy them one by one.

I am currently using Eclipse CDT, and it allows me to generate a list using the 'Outline' function, but unfortunately I am not able to copy them.

PS: I need this for documentation purposes.

Comment: You could check how a documentation generator like [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) extracts functions and variables.

Comment: Why are you defining variables in a header file?  And why 2000 of them?

Comment: this is where perl and shell excel; you're asking the wrong question and will therefore fail to find a real answer

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Thanks, Doxygen worked like a charm.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : Its an embedded RTOS, its necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html).  Just issue

```
ctags -x common.h
```

from a terminal.  A version of ctags for Windows also exists.